# How to know the current brightness and reddiness with redshift?

Tags: redshift

`redshift` sets how bright and reddish will show the display. Say that the system is adjusted by executing

```
redshift -l 55:55 -t 3600:3600
```

After setting them, is there any way to read these data out?

Comment: You can use verbose mode with -v to see the output values when issuing the above command. I *think* you can also just use `redshift -v` to get the current output even when not setting anything. But I can't check it right now. ;)